# MySQL where condition when intersecting 2 values (comma delimited)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have table like this:

```
    id  products  
------  ----------
     5  1,2,3     
     6  2,4,5     
     9  1,4,7     
    17  4,6,7     
    18  1,6,8     
    19  2,3,6
```

I have to select only that rows, which row's `products` column contains one of `(2,3)` values.

In this case query must return:

```
    id  products  
------  ----------
     5  1,2,3     
     6  2,4,5            
    19  2,3,6
```

But I don't understand how to make construction of this query.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need to select if there is at leas one mutch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you mind to try this one please?

```
select * from TABLE_NAME where products regexp "(^|,)[23](,|$)";
```

Its doing either two or three at the begining, or at end. Or in between the commas.

Comment: This is good idea, but it will not work properly if I wont to output that row, which column's value is "23, 24, 25". yes?

Comment: (^|,)((23)|(24)|(25))(,|$)

Comment: but it will return the id which products  has following value 235,2456 also

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id,products
FROM yourTable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2',products)>0
   OR FIND_IN_SET('3',products)>0
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ec51/1/0)

Comment: Ok, this works perfectly. I'll generate query with `PHP` and will add `FIND_IN_SET` conditions for all key values.

Thanks!

Comment: you can put `WHERE 0` then in `PHP` just generate a bunch of of `OR FIND_IN_SET(...`

Answer (score 0):

### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column.

Like you see now this will only give you headaches. Normalize your table. Then you can select normally.

Your table should look like this

```
id  product
--  -------
 5  1   
 5  2   
 5  3      
 6  2
 6  4
 6  5
 ...
```

With that table structure your select would be

```
select id
from your_normalized_table
where product in (2,3)
group by id
having count(distinct product) = 2
```

That query can make use of indexes and is really fast.

Comment: I got what you said, but in this case I have multiple records with same `id`. In this table I should have all rows with unique `id`s.

Comment: This sounds like better using **another** table. It is called a *N to M relation*. Example tables: `customers`, `products` and a new mapping table `product_orders`

Comment: yep, in this case N to N relation will be the best solution I guess. (men database performance)